# Angular Material md-current-view doens't work

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

all

I'm trying to use md-current-view with md-datepicker. But it doesn't work. 
Ultimately, I want to select months on a year-view without a choice of days.

My code:

```
<md-datepicker 
    md-current-view = "year" 
    datepicker-iso-date-format 
    ng-model="viewedDate" 
    md-placeholder="Enter date" 
    name="firstDatapicker" 
    class="only-icon md-primary select-time-range" 
    ng-change="selectMonthDatapicker(viewedDate)" 
    ng-click="selectDate($event)">
</md-datepicker>
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: *datepicker-iso-date-format* is not a supported attribute of md-datepicker. Did you add an extra directive ?